# Show a block on the user registration form depending on destination parameter

Tags: 7, users

How can I show a block, or a a mini panel, on the user registration form depending on the destination parameter?

Right now, I'm showing, in a view, a link that leads the users to user/register?destination=courses. This works fine, but I want to show  certain infomation to the still anonymous users who are going to register an account.

Comment: Try the [Block Conditional Visibility by URI Query Parameters](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_query) module.

Comment: @runswithscissors – Nice find! Drop an answer linking the module and quoting the module's description.

Answer (score 0):

As @runswithscissors pointed out this module does the trick [Block Conditional Visibility by URI Query Parameters](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_query) Thank you!

### Step 1

Download and enable `drush en block_query`

### Step 2

Go to blocks `admin/structure/block` and create a block or enable one of your choice. There are no specific configurations elsewhere. It's a very lightweight feature.

### Step 3

At the page of your block, under the "Visibility settings" you will now see "Queries" to "show block on specific pages", add the query parameter ONLY. 
E.g. if you have a destination parameter that leads to that particular page, only add the part behind the question mark `?`, not the entire path.

### Test it out

Let us know if it worked for you too.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]